# Azure data factory copy activity fails. Login failed for user

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory

We are trying to copy data from on prem SQL server to azure blob storage through data factory copy activity.

1. Installed data management gateway and connect.
2. build copy pipeline to copy a table to azure blob, which ran fine for a week

We are recently seeing this error since 2 days now

> Copy activity encountered a user error at Source side: ErrorCode=UserErrorFailedToConnectToSqlServer,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Cannot connect to SQL Server: '', Database: '', User: ''.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary,''Type=System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException,Message=Login failed for user 'chinese char displayed here'.,Source=.Net SqlClient Data Provider,SqlErrorNumber=18456,Class=14,ErrorCode=-2146232060,State=1,Errors=[{Class=14,Number=18456,State=1,Message=Login failed for user 'chinese char displayed here'.,},],'.

Client is able to login into sql server with same credentials given in data management gateway. checked the status of management gateway and it is fine and even ran a diagnostic check of connection from management gateway

Answer (score 1):

Refer to Step 8 thru 12 of the [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-factory-move-data-between-onprem-and-cloud#create-gateway) in order to ensure an active certificate and connection to Azure Data Factory. Next, View Logs in the Diagnostics tab to further assess the issue outside of Data Factory. Lastly, ensure your on-prem linked service in ADF is correctly deployed. If your destination linked service is utilizing an SasToken, ensure it is up to date as follow:

```
{  
    "name": "StorageSasLinkedService",  
    "properties": {  
        "type": "AzureStorageSas",  
        "typeProperties": {  
            "sasUri": "<storageUri>?<sasToken>"   
        }  
    }  
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: we were in a hurry and we recreated the copy activities using existing linked services and it worked. rerunning older jobs would fail but creating new ones works. i would gladly try these steps the next time i face this issue. thanks